# Part of method not running

Tags: c#

```
 static void getGrades()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How many grade level classes are you taking?");
        int standardNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("How many honors level classes are you taking?");
        int honorsNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("How many AP level classes are you taking?");
        int apNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your letter grades when prompted.");
        Console.WriteLine("=======================================");
        for (int a = 1; a == standardNumber; a++)
        {
            int num = 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter letter grade for honors class {0}:", num);
            switch (num)
            {
                case 1:
                    string class1 = Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    string class2 = Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    string class3 = Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    string class4 = Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }


            Console.WriteLine();

        }
    }
```

I'm trying to call this method to collect number of classes and grade letters from a mix of 4 classes. When I call the method, the first part (below) executes fine.

```
    Console.WriteLine("How many grade level classes are you taking?");
    int standardNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("How many honors level classes are you taking?");
    int honorsNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("How many AP level classes are you taking?");
    int apNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

However, the rest of the code (below) does not execute.

```
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your letter grades when prompted.");
    Console.WriteLine("=======================================");
    for (int a = 1; a == standardNumber; a++)
    {
        int num = 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter letter grade for honors class {0}:", num);
        switch (num)
        {
            case 1:
                string class1 = Console.ReadLine();
                break;
            case 2:
                string class2 = Console.ReadLine();
                break;
            case 3:
                string class3 = Console.ReadLine();
                break;
            case 4:
                string class4 = Console.ReadLine();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


        Console.WriteLine();

    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening. Thanks in advance

Comment: what you are trying to do here?

Comment: I am trying to get number of each type of class (ex 2 honors & classes 2 ap classes) and then use the loop to get the letter grade from however many of that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method contains these two lines in a row:

```
int apNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine();
```

There are two ways that it's possible for the first line to execute, but the second line not to:

- The method call `Console.ReadLine()` never returns because the user never presses "enter".
- Either the method `Console.ReadLine` or the method `int.Parse` throws an exception.

My guess is that `int.Parse` is throwing an exception.

---

A more theoretical answer:

If I'm not mistaken, when the code that I quoted runs, one of the following **must** happen, always, no matter what:

- The first line continues executing forever.
- The first line throws an exception.
- The thread is terminated before the second line executes.
- The first line returns and the second line executes.

If the last thing doesn't happen, one of the other things must be happening.

Answer (score 1):

According to your logic, if you enter the input **`standardNumber`**  as 1 only it will run these lines,

```
 for (int a = 1; a == standardNumber; a++)
 {
   int num = 1;    
}
```

btw, You dont need a for loop for that.

**EDIT:**

You need to store the inputs in a collection and do a loop on that

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> inputs = new List<int>();
            Console.WriteLine("How many grade level classes are you taking?");
            int standardNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            inputs.Add(standardNumber);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("How many honors level classes are you taking?");
            int honorsNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            inputs.Add(honorsNumber);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("How many AP level classes are you taking?");
            int apNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            inputs.Add(apNumber);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your letter grades when prompted.");
            Console.WriteLine("=======================================");
            for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Count; i++)
            {                
                Console.WriteLine("Enter letter grade for honors class {0}:", inputs[i]);
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 1:
                        string class1 = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        string class2 = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        string class3 = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        string class4 = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
```